# error while querying Calendar API?

Tags: android, calendar

There are some new API s added with icecream - Sandwich release . I am trying to get the duration details from the Calendar APi .

I used the following code

```
Cursor cursorEvent = CalendarContract.EventDays.query(getContentResolver(),1,1, null);
```

but i get the following SQLite exception.

> 11-04 20:49:14.918: E/AndroidRuntime(10135): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: selected: ,
>   while compiling: SELECT eventEndTimezone, visible, rrule, hasAlarm,
>   rdate, dtstart, hasAttendeeData, calendar_timezone, startDay,
>   description, calendar_access_level, account_type,
>   hasExtendedProperties, eventLocation, dtend, allDay, organizer,
>   Events.deleted as deleted, account_name, originalInstanceTime,
>   selfAttendeeStatus, eventTimezone, ownerAccount, endDay,
>   canOrganizerRespond, endMinute, Instances.event_id AS event_id,
>   lastDate, canModifyTimeZone, guestsCanModify, exrule,
>   guestsCanSeeGuests, title, Instances._id AS _id, _sync_id,
>   allowedReminders, end, availability, startMinute, calendar_id,
>   original_id, originalAllDay, maxReminders, accessLevel, begin,
>   calendar_color, duration, calendar_displayName, original_sync_id,
>   guestsCanInviteOthers, eventColor, exdate, eventStatus FROM Instances
>   INNER JOIN view_events AS Events ON (Instances.event_id=Events._id)
>   WHERE (startDay<=? AND endDay>=?) AND (selected=1) GROUP BY startDay

Can anyone help me fix this issue . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late, but I think the name of that column is "visible" from SDK v.14 (and "selected" before that):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#VISIBLE